# Macro for C++ to read and output from files

Tags: c++, macros

So I do competitive programming and I often need to use files, so I usually do it like this:

```
ifstream fin ("fileName.in");
ofstream fout ("fileName.out");
```

But I want to make a macro to do this in one line, something like this:

```
#define file(name); {ifstream fin(#name".in"); ofstream fout(#name."out");}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work with your macro definition? You could just try to write some testing part, given that macros are just litterally expanded in your code, does that compile and look right when you do that?

Comment: The sanity of doing this notwithstanding (are you *trying* to obfuscate your code?), `file(name);` <<== what's with that semicolon? And the curly braces? Those file objects will be in their own little scope, construct, destruct on scope exit, and no one outside of that scope will be the wiser.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not to mention that `fin` and `fout` won't be accessible outside that weird scope defined there.

Comment: @WhozCraig I use semicolon and {} because that's how you should make a macro which use a parameter that you give him like this: "#define debug(x); {cout<<#x<<"="<<x<<", ";}".

Comment: @R0L3eX Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did and now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use that pattern so much that you want to make a macro out of it, you probably also check that opening the file works, so I suggest adding that check to the macro too.

The curly braces around the expanded macro limits the scope of the variables so you can't use them after the macro has been expanded. Concatenating string literals can be done like this: `"this""is""a""string"` which becomes the same as `"thisisastring"`.

So, something like this should work:

```
#include <fstream>

#define with_file(name) std::ifstream fin(name".in"); std::ofstream fout(name".out"); if(fin&&fout)

int main() {
    with_file("the_file") {
        // use fin and fout
    }
}
```